# problem with drupal view and php code

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I have a view set up in drupal and I am using some jquery code within the view which hides some data based upon a text box value.
Everything is working fine for me when I am logged in.  When I log out and access the block anonymously, it doesn't work correctly.

I am somewhat new to drupal, and don't know where to begin troubleshooting.  I assume it is a permissions issue, but on the view, on the content type, where?

If anyone could give me some direction on where to start looking, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the Caching settings under Performance. If you disable everything, it should look the same for anon as it does authenticated.

You may also want to try disabling just Block Caching and see if that fixes it for you.

Comment: That doesn't seem to have done anything.  I have set up a custom template within my theme to set up the layout I needed for my view, and it seems to not be able to see that.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem - I didn't have the view permissions granted to anonymous users for my custom content type fields.  I checked the appropriate boxes under permissions and it is now working.

Thanks

Comment: Ah. The way you described the problem sounds like a caching issue as well. I didn't know you had view permissions enabled.